# Ag-Grid detect which key was pressed during onRowEditingStopped

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

In ag-grid, how can I ignore user's changes when Escape key was pressed?

I have a simple grid with all editable columns, and row edit turned on. I'd like to prevent an API call when user pressed escape button, but make this call when user pressed enter.

Below, simplified code:

```
<AgGridReact<T> onRowEditingStopped={onRowEditingStopped} rowModelType="serverSide" editType="fullRow"/>

const onRowEditingStopped = (event: RowValueChangedEvent<T>) => { 
    if(escapePressed()) return; 
    if(enterPressed()) saveDataToDb(event.data);
}
```

QUESTION: How would I implement `escapePressed` and `enterPressed`?

I'd think that `event.event` would have some data but it's unfortunately always undefined.